# setup AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh in git repository on ubuntu

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am receiving the following error when I run the setup for AWSDevTools inside my git repo.

`[[: not found
 cp: cannot stat`/home/user/aws/.git/scripts': No such file or directory`

I copied the scripts folder from the AWSDevTools .zip directly to the git repo and then received this error:

`[[: not found
 cp: cannot create directory`.git/AWSDevTools': No such file or directory`

copied AWSDevTools from .zip to the repository as well thinking the installer just wanted these folders in the repo to run but I continued to receive the same directory error. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume your repo is at `/home/user/aws/` (`.git` folder inside),

Your AWSDevTools are at `/home/user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3/AWSDevTools/Linux`

Then you should be able to follow these steps:

1) Open a command prompt, `cd` to `/home/user/aws` (your repo)

2) Run `/home/user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh`.

3) `git aws.config`

4) Enter AWS details

Then you can `git add`, `git commit`, and `git aws.push`. Let me know what error you get with these steps.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I was able to do this just had to use a prior version of AWSDevTools.

Comment: Good answer. I was trying to run the `AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh` outside of the project I was trying to push, and was getting errors. This cleared it up for me!