# How do I configure git on a nitrous io box to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, nitrousio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ruby application developed on a Nitrous IO box that I'm trying to deploy to an existing AWS Elastic Beanstalk application.  Git is configured on my Nitrous box and running "git status" returns:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I also can run a "git push" and my code is pushed to github.

I've installed the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool 2.6.2 package.  Running "eb status" returns the proper information about my EB instance.

However running "git aws.push" returns:

```
git: 'aws.push' is not a git command.
```

Reading the AWS documentation it says I need to run **AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh** but I can not locate this script on my Nitrous box.  Where is this script located or is there some other way to configure git to push to AWS EB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh was not previously included in the 2.6.2 package of Autoparts, but it can now be found when installing the latest version (2.6.3).

Run `$ parts update` to ensure the package manager is updated, and `$ parts install elasticbeakstalk` to install the latest version.

Once you have AWS Elastic Beanstalk 2.6.3 installed, you will need to run the repository setup tool in each git repository:

```
$ AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

From there you can run the AWS git commands:

```
$ git aws.config
$ git aws.push
```

Comment: Upgrading to the 2.6.2 package resolved this issue, however I also had to install the **boto** package in order to successfully run **git aws.push**. To install **boto** on Nitrous run the following:

Comment: **pip install virtualenv**; **virtualenv venv**; **source venv/bin/activate**; **pip install boto**

Answer (score 1):

`AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh` is located in `AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool`.

Just run this:

```sh
# I believe you remember where you placed the tool
$ find [PATH_TO_ELASTICBEANSTALK_CLI] -name AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
# If you don't remember
$ sudo find / -name AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

In my case it is in `$HOME`, so I got:

```sh
$ find ~/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/ -name AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

Check this answer out too: [setup AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh in git repository on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324724/setup-awsdevtools-repositorysetup-sh-in-git-repository-on-ubuntu)

PS Don't forget to change to your repo directory before you run `AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh`

Comment: Sorry this did not help - I can not locate AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh on my Nitrous box.  I do not have root access so the find command you sent gets an error.  I did find a directory called ~/.parts/packages/elasticbeanstalk/2.6.2 but it does not contain the script (the command find ~/.parts/packages/elasticbeanstalk/ -name AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh returns nothing)

Comment: But you said you installed Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool 2.6.2 package. Maybe you did that on your local machine? In this case you need to install it on your Server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$ cd ~
$ wget "https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk/cli/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3.zip"
$ unzip AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3.zip
$ cd workspace/your_app
$ sh ~/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
$ git aws.push
```